# Frequency table from two filters and two summarise in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

How can I combine the following codes to into one:

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>% filter(MIAPRFCD_J8==1 | MIAPRFCD_55==1) %>% summarise (Freq = n()) 


df %>% group_by(year) %>% filter(sum==1 | (MIAPRFCD_J8==1 & MIAPRFCD_55==1)) %>% summarise (reason_lv = n())
```

So output will be one table (or df) which is grouped by year and two columns of frequencies based on the above filters.
Here is the sample data:

```
df<- read.table(header=T, text='Act year    MIAPRFCD_J8 MIAPRFCD_55 sum
1   2015    1   0   1
2   2016    1   0   1
3   2016    0   1   2
6   2016    1   1   3
7   2016    0   0   2
9   2015    1   0   1
11  2015    1   0   1
12  2015    0   1   2
15  2014    0   1   1
20  2014    1   0   1
60  2013    1   0   1')
```

Output after combing the codes would be:

```
year Freq reason_lv
2013 1 1
2014 2 2
2015 4 3
2016 3 2
```

Comment: "I am not adding my data as I believe it is clear from the codes what I am trying to achieve." It really isn't. If you included your data, we'd know what types of variables you have, how you might join them, etc.

Comment: There's `group_by(mtcars, am) %>% summarise(n1 = sum(mpg > 20), n2 = sum(disp < 100))` but it seems like tally or a similar function should be usable instead...

Comment: It is not clear, actually.  Please always assume that what you do is not clear to your audience.

Comment: Agree with camille. Generally there is no excuse not to include data when asking `dplyr` questions; if you don't want to include your own data, use one of the many datasets made available by your installed packages (use `data(package = .packages(all.available = TRUE))` to see said datasets).

Comment: @camille et al. thanks for your feedback. I have now added a sample df for the above problem.

Comment: @akrun could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've included your data, this is easy enough to solve. Here are two possible options. Both options get you the output you want, it's mostly just a matter of style.

Option 1, make 2 filtered data frames, then use an `inner_join` to join them together by year. (You could also just build those data frames inline in the arguments to `inner_join`, but that's a little less clear.)

```r
library(tidyverse)

df<- read.table(header=T, 
    text='Act year    MIAPRFCD_J8 MIAPRFCD_55 sum
    1   2015    1   0   1
    2   2016    1   0   1
    3   2016    0   1   2
    6   2016    1   1   3
    7   2016    0   0   2
    9   2015    1   0   1
    11  2015    1   0   1
    12  2015    0   1   2
    15  2014    0   1   1
    20  2014    1   0   1
    60  2013    1   0   1') 

# option 1: two dataframes, then join
freq_df <- df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    filter(MIAPRFCD_J8 == 1 | MIAPRFCD_55 == 1) %>% 
    summarise (Freq = n()) 

reason_df <- df %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    filter(sum == 1 | (MIAPRFCD_J8 == 1 & MIAPRFCD_55 == 1)) %>% 
    summarise (reason_lv = n())

inner_join(freq_df, reason_df, by = "year")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    year  Freq reason_lv
#>   <int> <int>     <int>
#> 1  2013     1         1
#> 2  2014     2         2
#> 3  2015     4         3
#> 4  2016     3         2
```

Option 2, add boolean variables for whether the observation needs to go into the Freq calculation, and whether it needs to go into the response calculation--dummy variables help with this since those two things aren't mutually exclusive.

```r
# option 2: binary variables
df %>%
    mutate(getFreq = (MIAPRFCD_J8 == 1 | MIAPRFCD_55 == 1)) %>%
    mutate(getReason = (sum == 1 | (MIAPRFCD_J8 == 1 & MIAPRFCD_55 == 1))) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarise(Freq = sum(getFreq), reason_lv = sum(getReason))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>    year  Freq reason_lv
#>   <int> <int>     <int>
#> 1  2013     1         1
#> 2  2014     2         2
#> 3  2015     4         3
#> 4  2016     3         2
```

Created on 2018-04-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I like the option 2 much much better than option 1 (I was trying to avoid any join/merge). thanks so much!!